# Python, understanding Huffman code 2

Tags: python, huffman-code

I have been trying to understand Huffman code written in Python by [Rosetta code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Python)

I understand most of it and have made comments on some parts:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop, heapify 
from collections import defaultdict
import collections

txt = "abbaac!ccc" #txt is variable for string which will be encoded
symb2freq = collections.Counter(txt) #counts letter frequency
                                     #and puts in dictionary

def encode(symb2freq): #define a function

    heap = [[freq, [symbol, ""]] for symbol, freq in symb2freq.items()] #converts dictionary to a list in order to sort out alphabets in terms of frequencies

    heapify(heap) #This sorts out the list so that 1st element is always the
                  #smallest

    while len(heap) > 1:#while there is more than 1 element in the list

        left = heappop(heap) #Takes the lowest frequency from the list

        print("lo=", left)

        right = heappop(heap) #Takes the lowest frequency from the list        

        for x in left[1:]: 
            x[1] = '0' + x[1]
        for x in right[1:]:
            x[1] = '1' + x[1]
        add_freq= [left[0] + right[0]] + left[1:] + right[1:] #adds the frequencies and inserts frequency, symbol and alphabet (0 or 1) into one list e.g. [3, ['!', '0'], ['b', '1']]

        heappush(heap, add_freq )#inserts add_freq into heap

    return sorted(heappop(heap)[1:], key=lambda p: (len(p[-1]), p)) #What is this doing?

huff = encode(symb2freq)
print ("Symbol\tWeight\tHuffman Code")
for p in huff:
    print ("%s\t%s\t%s" % (p[0], symb2freq[p[0]], p[1]))
```

There is one line that I don't understand:

```
return sorted(heappop(heap)[1:], key=lambda p: (len(p[-1]), p)) #What is this doing?
```

I've changed it a little bit to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

heap has after the while loop only one element left.

heappop(heap) should get you this last element.

heappop(heap)[1:] takes the whole list of this last heap element and removes the first element, I am not sure why.

Then this list is sorted by sorted(..., key=lambda p: (len(p[-1]), p))
This means that the order in this list is rearranged according to the function defined in key. This function sorts the list by the length of the element or by the element it self. This should order your huffman codes from the shortest to the longest.

So this line basically does a sorting of the generated codes.